# Using a switch statement for a JComboBox

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox set up as shown below:

```
private String[] boxChoices = {"option 1", "option 2"};
JcomboBox box = new JCombobox(boxChoices);

box.addItemListener()
{ 
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)  
    {
        int selection = box.getSelectedIndex();
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 0: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have selected option 1");
                break;
            case 1: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have selected option 2");
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that when I pick an option the message will be shown twice instead of once. For example if I choose Option 1 the following would appear:

```
you have selected option 1
you have selected option 1
```

What is causing this to happen?

Comment: Please can you edit this by pasting in your actual code? This needs several changes before it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Blip's answer, you can also use actionListener. An actionEvent for JComboBox is only triggered once when you change a selection.

```
box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            int selection = box.getSelectedIndex();
            switch (selection) {
                case 0:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have selected option 1");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have selected option 2");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour occurs because Item listener is called 2 times because of selection of any item in the `JComboBox`. The first is called for deselection of previously selected item and the second time it is called for selection of the new item.

You can filter this by using a `if` clause to reflect the actual event you want to catch i.e. Selection or deselection :

```
if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
```

OR

```
 if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
```

based on your preference of choice of state change you want to trap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it could be because you're using an anonnymous listener.

Implement the `ItemListener` and add it.